# zend framework 2 : A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2.

Today I was trying to implement a simple database operation. I was referring to  https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html.

But I am getting following error

**A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager**

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code, that would help. But it seems like you try to call `getServiceLocator()` on the PluginManager class, which you shouldn't, but that is kinda obvious, see the error message you pasted.

Comment: you're not calling that inside the template are you?

Comment: Are you using ZF 2.5 or greater? If so then you can't use $this->getServiceLocator(); in your controller as this has been removed.

Comment: you'll have to post more code if you need some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a note:** `ZF2` is warning since a long time now about the depreciation of the use of `$this->getServiceLocator()` in the code and so we should respect it.

But still some of us have projects already developed with old code and we can't change all that now so had to find this solution.

Try adding `"zendframework/zend-mvc": "2.6.3"` to the `composer.json` file under `require` list like the following:

```
"require": {
    ....
    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "2.6.3",
    ....
}
```

This will allow you to make use of the `$this->getServiceLocator()` in the controller.

What this does is - even if the framework version gets on updating, the `zend-mvc` will always remain old in you code and support the use of `$this->getServiceLocator()`.

I know that most of them won't like this usage but it will definitly helps those who have got no way to upgrade/modify their code.

I hope it helps someone.